# Scala implicit conversion not recognised

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have the following object for making a conversion of an object `ParsedItemDocument` to a `json` String. I should note that `ParsedItemDocument` is a `trait`. My problem is that the implicit conversion that is called on the second snippet is not recognized by the compiler. Is there anything more that needs to be done for the implicit conversion to work?

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import wikidataParser.ParsedItemDocument


object Converters {

def toJson(obj: Any): String = {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val out = new StringWriter
    mapper.writeValue(out, obj)
    return out.toString()
    }    


   implicit def parsedItemDocumentToJsonString
  (item: ParsedItemDocument): String = {
      Converters.toJson(item)
   }
}
```

Now, I use the following code-snippet in my code

```
import tools.Converters._
 import wikidataParser.ParsedItemDocument

class WikipediaRankingTester2 extends FlatSpec {

"It" should "do something" in {
     val jsonrdd:RDD[String]=rankedItems.map(t:Long,ParsedItemDocument)=>
      t._2.parsedItemDocumentToJsonString)//compilation error here
 }
}
```

Comment: There are no explicit coversions needed in this snippet. Your compilation error is caused by the fact that your code is syntactically wrong.(parenthesis are unbalanced, t is declared to be Long, etc), not by implicit conversions. My advice to you would be to forget about implicits for now and concentrate on mastering the scala syntax and basic concepts instead.

Comment: Related to the question (for searchers landing here) though not the body of the question: if your implicit conversion also takes an implicit parameter ... don't forget to have an implicit value available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up implicit conversions and implicit classes.

If you want to use `parsedItemDocumentToJsonString` as a "method" of an object of type `ParsedItemDocument`, then you would need to define your implicit as

```
implicit class JSONParsing(item: ParsedItemDocument): String {
  def parsedItemDocumentToJsonString = Converters.toJson(item)  
}
```

If you declare it as an implicit conversion, as you did, then it means that you can call any methods of `String` on an object of type `ParsedItemDocument`, as the object will be implicitly converted to a `String` through the implicit method.

Also, it is not great practice to declare an entire implicit class / conversion, unless you 1) cannot add it to the original class, or 2) will be reusing the conversion very often, and it would save great amounts of code/readability. This does not seem to be the case here, as you are only wrapping in `Converters.toJSON`, which is not very verbose, and jsut as readable.

PS: your syntax in your "map" is wrong, the right syntax would be

```
val jsonrdd = rankedItems.map(t => t._2.parsedItemDocumentToJsonString)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your implicit is working this should do it:

```
rankedItems.map(t => t._2)
```

You can test this by making the call explicit

```
rankedItems.map(t => parsedItemDocumentToJsonString(t._2))
```

If you want to add an extra method to a `ParsedItemDocument` you could use an implicit class, I don't think you need it but your code looks a bit that way.